# Krajee Bootstrap File-Upload Plugin - previewFileIconSettings

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using this [plugin](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input#option-previewfileiconsettings)

and i have setup the previewFileIconSettings like this

```
    previewFileIconSettings: {
        'docx': '<i class="fa fa-file-word-o text-primary"></i>',
        'xlsx': '<i class="fa fa-file-excel-o text-success"></i>',
        'pptx': '<i class="fa fa-file-powerpoint-o text-danger"></i>',
        'doc': '<i class="fa fa-file-word-o text-primary"></i>',
        'xls': '<i class="fa fa-file-excel-o text-success"></i>',
        'ppt': '<i class="fa fa-file-powerpoint-o text-danger"></i>',
        'pdf': '<i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o text-danger"></i>',
    },
```

And all is fine when choosing a new file i get the preview icons properly
[image]

like in this [DEMO](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-preview-icons-demo)

But if i go to edit page those files don't have the preview icon:

[image]

Is there a way to fix this?

update:

I have found this also...

http://plugins.krajee.com/file-preview-management-demo#preview-advanced

but there are no settings for changing the initial preview icons